# Why is the vector of angular momentum perpendicular to the plane of rotation?

Tags: angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, vectors, conventions, definition

I just don't understand this. I have read about the right hand rule, but I am finding it hard to take it on faith, and would like to have some proof.

Also, try not to make your explanation too mathematical. I would prefer something intuitive and conceptual.

Comment: Imagine a spinning top spinning on a table, or a small body orbiting some centre in a circular path. Where does your intuition tell you that the angular momentum "should" point? The short answer to your question is that we have _defined_ it to point perpendicular to the plane of motion, but I guess that doesn't help your intuition.

Comment: Should i just take this fact on faith, and trust the smart physics people?? I was thinking that it's because something that rotates, always does so on a horizontal or vertical z-axis(kind of like a wheel rotating on an axle). But i guess my intuition just says that the angular momentum should point in a circle-ish shape. But i guess that vectors should be straight...

Comment: Well, it is a definition, so I'm not sure there is any faith involved. If my parents define my name to be "Marius", it does not require any faith from any party, it is just a definition. The angular momentum of a body with velocity $\mathbf{v}$ about a point is defined to be $\mathbf{L} = \mathbf{r} \times m \mathbf{v}$ where $\mathbf{r}$ it the vector pointing from the point to the body.

Comment: Due to the mathematical properties of the vector product, if an object is moving in a 2D plane about a point that is _also in that plane_, then both $\mathbf{r}$ and $\mathbf{v}$ will lie in the plane, and the vectorproduct will be perpendicular to it.

Comment: There _is_ a vector quantity that follows the particle in a "circle-ish" shape when it moves around a circle, but that is just the velocity vector of the particle :) So the concept of angular momentum would not be that useful if it were also a vector like that; we would just use the velocity then.

Comment: I finally understand!! I just needed a little more knowledge on vector products, but a quick google search helped me out there! This was exactly what I was looking for! Thanks @MariusLadegårdMeyer

Comment: This question (v2) has undoubtedly been asked before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) If the body is moving in a  plane then it's position and velocity/momentum vectors are in that plane too. This is easy to verify.

2)Angular momentum is a cross product of position and momentum

3)A cross product is always perpendicular to the plane in which the vectors to be crossed are.

4) We conclude that the angular momentum is perpendicular to the plane in which the object is moving( of which rotation is a special case).

Comment: Angular *velocity* is normal to the plane of rotation. Angular momentum does not need to be in the same direction as angular velocity.

Comment: Hi sandejo, do you mean to say that angular momentum of a particle isn't necessarily perpendicular to the plane of motion?

Comment: @YasirSadiq yes for a particle moving in a plane if you choose a different origin which doesnt lie on the plane of motion.

Comment: @Jolie i agree, but i had assumed them to lie in the plane of motion. Thank you.

Comment: Ok wait you all are confusing me now! @Jolie , i thought the vector of angular momentum is always perpendicular to its plane of motion?

Comment: @Viradeus well I think I got you.. the confusion is between rigid bodies spinning like the spinning top and bodies rotating or moving with respect to some outside point that you choose. For the spinning of a rigid body case the angular velocity is defined along the axis of rotation and is independent of choice of frame.

Comment: @jolie that makes a little bit of sense... i was only thinking of the classic bicycle wheel spinning example, so would that be a rigid body or no? I don't think so, but I have just started learning physics so im not too clear on some of the stuff

Comment: @Viradeus it is a rigid body https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigid_body

Answer (score 2):

As with all mathematical conventions in physics, the reason why we represent something a certain way is because it is useful.

Angular velocity is a [pseudovector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudovector), so its direction is defined by the axis about which an object rotates, which makes the angular velocity vector [normal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2406260/difference-between-perpendicular-orthogonal-and-normal) to the plane of rotation. Angular momentum is defined by $$\vec L = I\vec\omega$$ while this may make it appear the angular momentum is in the same direction as angular velocity, this is actually only the case when the axis of rotation is one the the [principal axes of rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_of_inertia#Principal_axes), due the fact that the moment of inertia is actually represented by a [matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_of_inertia#Inertia_tensor).

There is no need to prove this is the angular momentum, as this is how it defined. The reason why we define it this way is, as stated above, because it is useful. For example, it follows a [conservation law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_momentum#Conservation_of_angular_momentum) and adds nicely.

Comment: A matrix is a bunch of numbers in a box. A tensor, on the other hand, is a geometric object and/or a multilinear function that maps vectors to vectors in a frame independent manner. $I$ is a tensor.

Comment: @JEB yes, but I thought the asker might be more familiar with matrices and might get confused if I said tensor. I have edited to clarify.

Comment: I think I understood. Angular momentum L is equal to the radius r times the momentum p, both of which are vector coordinates right? Hence, when we multiply vectors,we have something called a cross product. When multiplying cross products, we would get a cross product which is perpendicular to the 2d plane that the wheel was moving in. Would this be a correct explanation on why the direction of angular momentum is perpendicular to the plane of rotation?

Answer (score 2):

We say that angular momentum is perpendicular to the plane of rotation (in a simple case like a rotating disk) only because [Josiah Willard Gibbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josiah_Willard_Gibbs#Vector_analysis) and [Oliver Heaviside](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oliver_Heaviside) popularized vector algebra (including a vector product using the right-hand rule) and vector calculus in the early 1900’s.

There are more modern formalisms — not generally taught in high school and often not in universities either — in which angular momentum is represented as a tensor which one can visualize as lying in the plane of rotation. (Or a bivector, or a two-form, or an element in Clifford algebra, etc. There are *lots* of formalisms for representing directional physical quantities in multidimensional spaces!)

The different formalisms describe the same physics using different mathematical objects. There is no sense in which angular momentum is “really” perpendicular to the plane of rotation. In fact, in higher dimensions Gibbs’ vector product doesn’t even make sense because there is not a unique direction perpendicular to a plane.

All of these other formalisms are more in tune with your intuition that angular momentum should be a planar quantity. They are all capable of distinguishing the “$x$ toward $y$ plane” from the “$y$ toward $x$” plane, which is necessary to keep track of which way something is rotating.

As an example, you may be interested to read about [exterior algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra).

Answer (score 0):

The set of points unaffected by rotation forms a line, the axis of rotation, which is perpendicular to the plane of rotation. One can take this axis as defining the direction of angular momentum. However, AM, is a *pseudovector* . It is in reality an antisymmetric tensor and such objects have 3 components in 3D. Coincidentally this can be treated as something akin to a vector. As I said , it is really an antisymmetric tensor, $\vec r \times \vec p$, and this defines, guess what, a surface parallel to the plane of rotation, as in Kepler's second law. Does this help you to get an intuition?